# How to check if an Android device has voice capabilities

Tags: android

Does anyone know a good way of programmaticaly checking if an Android device, phone or tablet, has voice capabilities?
By voice capabilities I mean capability to make phone calls. I know there are devices, like Galaxy tab in North America, that don't have this capability.

Answer (score 3):

I haven't tried this myself, but it looks like the details you need would be in the TelephonyManager:

```
private boolean hasPhoneAbility()
{
   TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
   if(telephonyManager.getPhoneType() == TelephonyManager.PHONE_TYPE_NONE)
       return false;

   return true;
}
```

Comment: I tryed this method and for Galaxy Tab, with no voice call capability it returns PHONE_TYPE_GSM.

Comment: How about this: telephonyManager.getLine1Number() == null.  You'll need the permission READ_PHONE_STATE

Comment: Galaxy Tab even has a phone number.

Answer (score 1):

I know this question was posted a long time ago, but I still thought I would post the solution I came up with that works for me so far, just so anyone with the same problem can benefit. (Because it seems like lots of people are having trouble finding a solution).

I just checked for the device's voicemail number, and obviously if it doesn't have one, then it is not a phone. In my code, to check this, it is `tm.getVoiceMailNumber();`

Here's what I did:

```
callButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {

            TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager)getSystemService(TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
            String ableToMakePhoneCalls = tm.getVoiceMailNumber(); //check device for voicemail number (null means no voicemail number).

            if(ableToMakePhoneCalls == null){ //If the device does not have voicemail, then it must not be a phone. So it can't call.

                //I displayed an alert dialog box here


            }
            else{

                String phoneNum = "tel:8885554444";

                Intent intentPhone = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_CALL);
                intentPhone.setData(Uri.parse(phoneNum));

                startActivity(intentPhone);
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

In theory, you should be able to use `Intent.resolveActivity` to do this. There's a problem (described [here](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/165e52425904d637)) with Galaxy tabs in particular. They evidently report that they have calling capability. You can even resolve an intent successfully. Unfortunately, it resolves to a no-op activity.

Comment: I was hopping for something more specific like something from TelephonyManager that could be used...

Comment: The key point made by Mark Murphy in that thread I linked to is this: "Some Android 2.x tablets, like the Galaxy Tab, may claim to have telephony even if they do not have a dialer, in order to qualify for the Android Market. Short of using android.os.Build to identify these by manufacturer and model, I do not know how else you can tell." Unfortunately, there's no better answer. Every software test you can make on a Galaxy will tell you that it is phone-capable, even though it isn't.

Answer (score 0):

I would assume that prepare() would fail if there is not mic available:

```
  mRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
  mRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
  mRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
  mRecorder.setOutputFile(audio_file);
  mRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
  try {
      mRecorder.prepare();
      mRecorder.start();
  } catch (Exception e) {}
```