# Check if device can make call

Tags: android, android-intent, package-managers

I check capability via PackageManager

```
final PackageManager packageManager = context.getPackageManager();
        final Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
        List<ResolveInfo> list =
                packageManager.queryIntentActivities(intent, PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);
        return list.size() > 0;
```

But anyway result is false. Application was on tablet and phone, but result is the same. Where I was wrong?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6130180/how-to-check-if-an-android-device-has-voice-capabilities